# $ is not defined- You've used the same selector more than once- Selector: ".stripNav ul li a"

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hi It might be asked before but I am new to Jquery and using just simple script "Slider" and now i need other script on same page named "Gallery".
Both are working correctly on different pages but if i am trying to use both scripts on same page,  "Gallery" is working but not "Slider", firebug is saying,

"$ is not defined- You've used the same selector more than once- Selector: ".stripNav ul li a"

Could anybody help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to show us some code and give us a bit of background. Are you using jQuery.lint.js by any chance?

This stackoverflow post contains info from someone that encountered a similar problem:
[You've used the same selector more than once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3440970/youve-used-the-same-selector-more-than-once)